# Executing test cases when executing the SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

While executing a SQL script in production like sensitive database, usually I do the following

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

--Declare of test variables
DECLARE @ExpectedAffectedRows INT = 10 -- Manually count this
DECLARE @ActualAffectedRows INT = 0



-- Its a demo code, don't take it seriously ;P
DELETE * FROM SomeTable AS st WHERE st.ColumnA = 'A'
SET @ActualAffectedRows = @ActualAffectedRows + @@ROWCOUNT

UPDATE SomeTable
SET ColumnA = 'A' WHERE ColumnA='B'
SET @ActualAffectedRows = @ActualAffectedRows + @@ROWCOUNT

IF @@ERROR<>0 OR @ActualAffectedRows<>@ExpectedAffectedRows 
BEGIN 
    ROLLBACK 
    SET NOEXEC ON 
END

IF @@TRANCOUNT>0  
BEGIN 
    COMMIT 
END
```

The thing here, I hard coded the **@ExpectedAffectedRows** variable manually, counting how many rows will be affected.

Is the process fine or are there other superior processes or best practices to deal with this type of data update/delete things?

Comment: Are you trying to get away from manually counting the records?

Comment: I would prefer to run some checks afterwards to make sure no sensitive data is left. Deficits and surpluses in actually affected rows *may* compensate and still produce the expected number (although this would be sheer coincidence).